# Does Apple Catalyst support iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, mac-catalyst

There are many resources and tutorials mentioning `iPad` and/or `iOS` being compatible with Apple's `Catalyst` framework,
So, the same source-code runs on `Mac OS X` as well.
But **does Catalyst support iPhone?**
(Please tell me your personal experience to clarify this, and not that the name of iPhone operating-system is iOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mac Catalyst** allows iOS apps to be built for and run on macOS.

So, by definition, Catalyst apps support iOS, and *usually* the iPhone. The only case in which they wouldn't is if the app was specifically an iPad-only app that runs on Catalyst on the Mac, but was not enabled to run on the iPhone.

More about Catalyst: https://developer.apple.com/mac-catalyst/

You asked for personal experience: I have apps in the App Store for iOS, iPad, and Mac, via both Catalyst and non-Catalyst builds.